# Schengen visa ban

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, long-stay-visas, bulgaria

I am an Indian citizen and have a two year Schengen ban, due to an overstay in Latvia.

I would like to study in Bulgaria. Bulgaria is not a part of the Schengen zone.

Is the Schengen ban likely to cause issues with a long term visa application to Bulgaria?

Comment: Probably yes, since Bulgaria is in the process of joining the zone so it participates in most of its processes.